# Redireccionamiento automático typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, web

Estoy implementado un cuestionario en typescript (con Angular 10) que han de responder varios usuarios. Quisiera que, una vez hayan respondido todos los usuarios, les redireccionase automáticamente a una página de resultados.
Mi idea era crear una función con la siguiente estructura:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    //Código para comprobar cada dos segundos si todos los usuarios han respondido a las cuestiones y redireccionarlos a la página correspondiente si se da la condición
}, 2000);
```

En mi caso, existe un array con 10 posiciones (son un total de 10 preguntas), siendo sus valores 1 (si todos los usuarios han contestado) o 0 (si falta alguien por responder), concretamente mi intención era aplicar el código expuesto de la siguiente forma:

```
var contador:number=0;
setInterval(function(){ 
    for(let i=0;i<arrayrespuestas.length;i++){
       if(arrayrespuestas(i)>0){
         contador =contador+1;
}}
if(contador==10){
this.router.navigate(['/app/resultados']);
}
contador=0;}, 2000);
```

Acto seguido llamaría a la función para que pudiese ejecutarse. El problema que me surge está relacionado con un error de this, concretamente:

'this' implicity has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.

Y no encuentro cómo incluir el redireccionamiento recurriendo a otra expresión alternativa.

Gracias de antemano por las respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usar una función flecha resolvería el problema. La razón: la función flecha no crea su propio contexto así que usa el contexto donde es llamada.

```
var contador: number = 0;
setInterval(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayrespuestas.length; i++) {
        if (arrayrespuestas(i) > 0) {
            contador = contador + 1;
        }
    }
    if (contador == 10) {
        this.router.navigate(['/app/resultados']);
    }
    contador = 0;
}, 2000)
```